# How to fill the screen with an image on Android

Tags: android, imageview, screen

I'm working on mdpi, and when  I add a imageView to the activity it doesnt fill the screen, I tried setting the scaleType to fitXY but the image didnt fill the screen, also I'm using a relativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set width and height parameters as match_parent in your XML layout (instead of wrap_content)